# How to use Google Drive for .net application?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-drive-api, authorization

I've got a .net core application running on the server and I would like to store my app data directly on Google Drive. I use regular Google account for it with Google Drive API enabled (it seems to be enabled) and service account with credentials stored in json file. Here's code to create Google Drive service in my application:

```cs
private DriveService CreateDriveServiceClient() => new DriveService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(this.config.ClientEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new string[]
                {
                    DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                },
            }.FromPrivateKey(this.config.PrivateKey))
    });
```

It uses scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata`, which leads to string `drive.appdata`
However I get the following error:

`Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]`

when trying to acces at least `client.Drives.List().Execute();`
It seems to me that I need to add a role to access `drive.appdata` scope. But I can't find an appropriate role in Google console, neither I can't find this scope when creating a new role for service account

How can I add permissions to service account to use Google Drive?

Comment: So are you trying to access *user* data with a service account? Normally you'd need a user credential for that - or use impersonation if the service account is in the same GSuite org as the user.

Comment: can I authenticate with user credentials without Google's authentication page? I was able to create service account inside my regular account but can't grant permission. I would liike to avoid using GSuite if possible. But if it's the only way to achieve my goals, I'm ok with it.

Comment: I would be *very* worried if you could access user data without being in the same organization and without any authentication and authorization from that user - why should your application be able to read my Drive files without permission, for example? Typically you'd show the Google authentication page *once*, and store the access token and refresh token, so you can then access the user's data with their permission unless they revoke that permission.

Comment: I do not mean accessing data without any authentication. I mean authenticating from my API an using only my Google account to store my app data. It's not storing user's data, it's just for my application

Comment: It's *possible* that you can use regular Drive sharing to share your Drive (or a specific folder) using the email address of a service account - I've never tried it though, and it may well not work.

Comment: yes, I'm ok with sharing my Google Drive with service account, but can't properly grant permission

Comment: Well you can authenticate your Google account (using the authentication page) once, and then store that user credential data, and access it that way from your server. Do you specifically need Drive rather than (say) Google Cloud Storage, Firestore etc?

Comment: just looking for a place to store my local app data, and google drive seems good enough. but any other solutions are appreciated

Comment: Drive is more designed for user-oriented documents etc. I would suggest Firestore or Google Cloud Storage for this scenario - Firestore if you want to store data that you can query, get change notifications for etc, and Google Cloud Storage if you're happy just storing blobs. Both of these are designed more for server-oriented access than user-oriented access, so you'll have a much easier time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**Google Drive API v3**](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list#auth) documentation:

> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

Therefore, if you want to be able to use the Drive API properly, you should change the scope to one of those provided above.

You can also test the API on the Google Drive API v3 [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list).

Furthermore, I suggest you check these links for more information:

- [Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list);
- [OAuth2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Comment: I still can't find `drive` and `drive.readonly` when setting up permissions for service account or a role in console

Comment: Hello @Waldemar, thank you for your reply. You could try and replace the `DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata` with `DriveService.Scope.Drive` since your line of code references to the `.appdata` scope. What is the result of this execution? Cheers!

Comment: the problem is that I cant find permissions for `.appdata` either

Comment: Hello @Waldemar, you only need to change the permissions in your code. Cheers!